# Computing gradient with respect to more variables than the function

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

Suppose I have a function $f(\boldsymbol{x})$ defined on $\mathcal{X}$. I would like to compute this
$$
\nabla_{\boldsymbol{x},\, \boldsymbol{y}} \int_{\mathcal{X}} f(\boldsymbol{x}) d\boldsymbol{x}
$$
where $\boldsymbol{y}$ is some other set of variables. Basically I am taking the gradient not only with respect to $\boldsymbol{x}$ but also with respect to $\boldsymbol{y}$. I have essentially defined a new variable $\boldsymbol{\xi} : =(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y})$ and then I am taking the gradient $\nabla_{\boldsymbol{\xi}}$.

## My Working

I think that $\nabla_{\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y}} f(\boldsymbol{x}) = (\nabla_{\boldsymbol{x}} f(\boldsymbol{x}), \nabla_{\boldsymbol{y}} f(\boldsymbol{y}))$ and so
$$
\nabla_{\boldsymbol{x},\, \boldsymbol{y}} \int_{\mathcal{X}} f(\boldsymbol{x}) d\boldsymbol{x} = \int_{\mathcal{X}} (\nabla_{\boldsymbol{x}} f(\boldsymbol{x}), \nabla_{\boldsymbol{y}} f(\boldsymbol{y})) d\boldsymbol{x} = \int_{\mathcal{X}} \nabla_{\boldsymbol{x}}f(\boldsymbol{x}) d\boldsymbol{x}  + \int_{\mathcal{X}}\nabla_{\boldsymbol{y}} f(\boldsymbol{x}) d\boldsymbol{x} = \int_{\mathcal{X}} \nabla_{\boldsymbol{x}}f(\boldsymbol{x}) d\boldsymbol{x}  + 0 = \int_{\mathcal{X}} \nabla_{\boldsymbol{x}}f(\boldsymbol{x}) d\boldsymbol{x} 
$$
Does this make any sense?

Comment: where is the $y$ dependence coming from?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Let me clarify! Basically the above is an abstraction of something that I found in a calculation. Essentially I had the function $g(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y}) = h(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y}) + f(\boldsymbol{x})$ for some functions $g$ and $h$. Then I had to compute the gradient with respect to $(\boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y})$ i.e.
$$
\nabla_{x, y} g(x, y) = \nabla_{x,y} h(x, y) + \nabla_{x,y} f(x)
$$
And so I need to compute $\nabla_{x, y} f(x)$.

Comment: Sure, in which case the gradient of the $f$ part is just the gradient in $x$ followed by a bunch of zeros. But I’ll remark that mathematically what you wrote in the question should have an identically zero gradient. You cannot take the gradient in x of $\int_X f(x)dx$ in that way, as the $x$ is already ‘integrated out’

Comment: Concretely: what is $\frac d{dx}(\int_0^1 x^2 dx)$? The answer is $0$. Working: $$\frac d{dx}\left(\int_0^1 x^2 dx\right) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac13\right) = 0.$$